# Get product name and url within phtml file - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, attributes

This must be relatively simple to do - but I am really struggling.

I have created a new phtml file 'newfile.phtml' that appears in the catalog\product\view section and displays the word 'hello' on the product page. I want to update this so it includes the product name and the product url. I have tried using the following:

```
<?php echo $product->getData('name'); ?>
```

However, nothing is returned with the above.

Can anyone suggest the cleanest way to get current product name from within a standard .phtml file?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define $product in your phtml ?  You should access it with a block or at least a this object I guess.
So you need to look where this block or this object is defined cause it's in that object you miss the data name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the class you have configured your template to use in the layout file. For example,

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="yourCustom.phtml">
```

will allow you to retrieve the product name and URL within yourCustom template using:

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$productName = $product->getName();
$productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load product to get product name

**With Object Manager**

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

Note: Don't use objectManager directly

**With Factory Method**

```
<?php

  protected $product;  

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->product->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

Then call `getProduct` function in your phtml file

```
$productId = "10"; //Product Id
$product=$this->getProduct($productId);

echo $product->getName(); //Get Product Name
```

If you want to get in current product information in phtml you can use following code.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product information
    echo $currentProduct>getId();
    echo $currentProduct>getName();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in magento 2 there are view models that allow you to do what you are looking for according to magento 2 best practice.
docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

follow the guide and implement a custom function using this class

`use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session as CatalogSession;`

Cheers